# How can I declare an array in one function and use that same array in another function?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, scope

Here is my code

```
class Employee{
     private String Animal;
     private int Quantity;

     Employee(String Animal, int Quantity){
     this.Animal=Animal;
     this.Quantity=Quantity;

     public String getAnimal{
            return animal;
     }

     public void setAnimal{
            this.Animal=Animal;
     }

     public String getQuantity{
            return Quantity;
     }

     public void setQuantity{
            this.Quantity=Quantity;
     }

     public static void Input(){
           Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
           int n = 0;
           Employee[] list = new Employee[20];
           list[no] = new Employee(" ", 0);

           String nameOfAnimal = sc.nextLine();
           list[n].setAnimal(nameOfAnimal);
       
           String numberOfAnimal = sc.nextLine();
           list[n].setQuantity(numberOfAnimal);
       
           ++n;
     }

     public static void Output(){
           ...
           for(int i=0; i<n; ++i){
           System.out.println(" -" + list[i].getAnimal + " - " + list[i].getQuantity);
           }
     }
}
```

In the Output method, I dot 3 points because I don't know how to get the array declared in the Input method and print its content within the Output method. It always shows an error that the first element is null when I create the same array in the Output function. Concisely, how can I keep an array that both functions can be used?

Comment: local variables? You can't. they're out of scope of the rest of the code. They seize to exist when the method has run it's course. use instance or class variables instead

Comment: Give `Input` the return type of `Employee[]` and return `list`. Add a parameter of type `Employee[]` to `Output` and pass the value which was returned from `Input`.